# Unexpected data in messaging event for guest using MS Teams bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a MS Teams bot set up in a customer's tenant. The bot is installed in one team. We use the Microsoft Bot Framework REST API & webhooks to receive messaging events from users to the bot, and make API requests to send messages to them.

We noticed today that one user sent us a message with an unexpected tenant ID. The tenant ID of the customer is X and we received a tenant ID of Y in the request body when the user messaged the bot.

We also noticed that the User ID did not match the User we find when listing Users in the one team the bot is installed. The Microsoft Graph object ID is not correct either. Finally, we noticed that the User is marked as a guest account when we look at their profile in the list of Users in the team where the bot is installed.

Why is this happening and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Could you please share the repro steps and sample code so that we can check it from our end?

Comment: ask your customer if this guest is invited by them? It just like someone unidentified installed your bot

Comment: Someone unidentified installed my bot? What does that mean and why the tenant ID be different? You think this user installed the bot on their own tenant? Seems unlikely, but I will ask

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft (1) Install a bot in a team (2) have a user in the team send a message to the bot (3) an HTTP request is sent by Microsoft's servers containing information about the messaging event. Obviously this normally works, but here the request body has a different tenant ID. Maybe they did it install it on their own tenant, but it just doesn't feel like it makes sense. I feel like it may be related to the user being a guest account, but I'm not sure. The "guest account" info comes from data received using the Bot Framework REST API when listing users in the team containing the bot.

Comment: Note that when looking at the profile of this user in this way, we find a different ID, different tenant ID, Microsoft Graph ID etc. than in the request body.

Comment: We added an external user to a team where our bot is installed. Guest users sends a message in team. We see the same Tenant ID and user ID while listing members in team and in context.activity.  
Could you please share the request/response IDs and body when  

 1. Guest user sends a message .
 2. Listing members of the team.

Please make sure you have removed any PII.

Comment: We're waiting for feedback from the customer and still trying to figure this out, if there's no progress I will send you more information, thanks for pinging me!!